# How do I get pen pressure values in Unity (using S Pen on Android)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stylus-pen

I've looked everywhere and there's no actual examples or tutorials regarding using tablet pens with Unity.

I tried using the GetTouch function I found on a forum just to see if that would work:

```
float pressure = Input.GetTouch(0).pressure;
```

then displaying the value as a string to see it's value, but I get a "Index out of bound" error.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install the package **Input System**

[image]

After that you have to add the namespace **UnityEngine.InputSystem** to your script (line 2).

[image]

The value can be read with `Pointer.current.pressure.clampConstant`

Further information can be found here

- [ControlsAxis​Control / Class Pointer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Pointer.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_Pointer_pressure)
- [​ControlsAxis​Control / Class AxisControl](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Controls.AxisControl.html)
- [Pen, tablet, and stylus support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Pen.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your thorough answer! The only problem I have is that it doesn't seem to recognize "stylus support" when running the app on my Galaxy Note 20. This statement always comes back false: if (Input.stylusTouchSupported). The pen clearly works, though, since I can "draw" in my app with it. But if I start using my fingers to draw, the pen stops working completely.

Comment: I'm glad. And what if you just leave that part `if Input.stylusTouchSupported` out?